# Calculating/choosing the right capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, fuses

For designing a pyrofuse driver, I need to add a capacitor that serves as an alternative power source in case of main power supply cut-off. The driver has a configurable firing pulse of 1.2A/2ms or 1.75A/0.5ms. During standby mode, it draws 3.6mA current to be kept alive. My question is how to calculate/choose the correct capacitor for this application? I would like to keep the design generic so I want to figure out the general rule in finding the appropriate capacitance.

Comment: What's the guaranteed range of impedance on your squib? From there and 1.2 A  for 2 ms, you have your energy requirement.

Comment: To calculate capacitance, you need to know how much the voltage must be at start and at the end of the timed sequence. It might be that a capacitor is not a solution you want. Does the 1.2A/2ms or 1.75A/0.5ms specs include any tolerances, and at what voltages?

Comment: How much can the voltage drop? When you start drawing energy from the cap, the voltage starts to drop. What is the initial voltage and the minimum required voltage?

Comment: The nominal voltage is 12V and the minimum voltage required to keep the circuit alive is  4V. The squib that can be fired has to be in the range of 3-5Ohm.

Comment: i am seeing so many formulas and I can't figure out which to use. After discharging the cap till it reaches the minimum voltage of 4V during standby mode, what calculations I need to make so that it will be able to provide this 1.2A/2ms pulse?

Comment: The calculations (or their description) do not match up. If you put a nominal 12V to 3-5 ohms it's 2.4-4.0 amps.